# Selenium tests fail after first test

Tags: python, django, selenium

I am trying to run selenium tests I've written for a Django project on a Debian server, using xvfb.

I have 3 tests I am trying to run, after the first test, they fail with this error:
NoSuchElementException: Message: u'Unable to locate element:    `{"method":"xpath","selector":"//a[@href=\\"#detail\\"]"}'`

I have run `export DISPLAY=:99` and am using Django LiveServerTestCase with django-selenium.
`SELENIUM_DISPLAY = ':99'` is set in my settings.py.

Here is my test runner:

```
class BaseLiveTest(LiveServerTestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.selenium = WebDriver()
        super(BaseLiveTest, cls).setUpClass()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        super(BaseLiveTest, cls).tearDownClass()
        cls.selenium.quit()

    def login(self, user):
        #helper function, to log in users
        #go to login page
        self.selenium.get("%s%s" % (self.live_server_url, reverse('userena_signin')))
        #wait for page to display
        WebDriverWait(self.selenium, 10).until(
            lambda x: self.selenium.find_element_by_id('id_identification'),
        )
        #fill in form and submit
        identifictation_input = self.selenium.find_element_by_id('id_identification')
        identifictation_input.send_keys(user.email)
        password_input = self.selenium.find_element_by_id("id_password")
        password_input.send_keys('password')
        self.selenium.find_element_by_xpath('//form/descendant::button[@type="submit"]').click()

        #wait for dashboard to load
        WebDriverWait(self.selenium, 10).until(
            lambda x: self.selenium.find_element_by_id('container'),
        )
```

When I run each test by itself they all pass, but if I try to run them one after another the last 2 fail. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `setUp()` and `tearDown()`, not `setUpClass()` and `tearDownClass()`.  The Class versions are run globally for the entire fixture, so all 3 tests are using the same `WebDriver` instance, and thus the browser isn't in the state you expect for your second and third tests.

Comment: Any ideas on why this would work locally and not on the server? Locally, I am running OSX with Firefox webdriver. The server is Debian, xvfb and iceweasel.

Comment: The tests would work 1 by 1, but not run in sequence.  Run 1 at a time explicitly, the class-level setup would run once per a test.