# Django LiveServerTestCase fails to load a page when I run multiple tests

Tags: python, django, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to run multiple tests within one Django LiveServerTestCase. When I run any single test (with others commented) everything works as expected. But when I run test case with two tests the first one works fine but the second one loads page with "internal server error" message.

Code:

```
from django.test import LiveServerTestCase
from selenium.webdriver.firefox.webdriver import WebDriver


class MyLiveServerTestCase(LiveServerTestCase):    
    """
    BaseCleass for my selenium test cases
    """
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.driver = WebDriver()
        cls.url = cls.live_server_url    

        super(MyLiveServerTestCase, cls).setUpClass()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.driver.quit()
        super(MyLiveServerTestCase, cls).tearDownClass()

class AdminEditFormTest(MyLiveServerTestCase):
    """
    Some test case
    """

    def test_valid_data(self):
        """
        test when user enters correct data
        """
        self.driver.get(self.url)
        # ...

    def test_invalid_data(self):
        """ test when user enters INcorrect data """
        self.driver.get(self.url)
        # ...
```

If I use `close()` instead of `quit()` it fails with "error 98: address already in use" similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20619846/djangos-liveservertestcase-always-fails-due-to-conflicting-address-despite-a) case except I have an error only when I have multiple tests in one LiveServerTestCase class or multiple test cases in one .py file.

How do I make LiveServerTestCase free port on tearDown (if it is the core problem)?

Is there any workaround? All I want are functional selenium tests running equally on local and remote servers.

I am using Django 1.6.7, Firefox 37.0, Selenium 2.45.0

**upd**

Using methods instead of classmethods leads to the same issue.

```
def setUp(self):
    self.driver = WebDriver()
    self.url = self.live_server_url    

def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.quit()
```

Comment: Does the second test run fine on it's own?

Comment: Yes, independently they run well.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and I'm trying to find a working and elegant solution (something better than put each test alone inside its own LiveServerTestCase class). Just to have more data to work on, which version of Django are you using?

Comment: Separate classes do not help as well. I am using django 1.6.7

Comment: I tried to replicate your situation by copy & paste your code into one of my working Django project, and I got no error at all. **I needed to update Firefox and Selenium, though**. Testing your code with `Firefox==37.0` and `Selenium==2.45.0` doesn't raise errors for me. Have you already tried to update them both? _Side note:_ if you have the occasion, try [PhantomJS](http://phantomjs.org/) instead of Firefox for your functional tests: it's _really_ faster!

Comment: I am using `Selenium==2.45.0` and `Firefox==36.0` (looks like latest in ubuntu)

Comment: I tested your code on Ubuntu, too. FF 37 should be available. Actually, `Selenium==2.45.0` had [an issue with FF 36](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=8399#c37), fixed one month ago. Try again to force the update for both, just to be sure =) Anyway, you talked about an "internal server error" message, raised when both tests are run one after the other. The terminal from which you launch the `python manage.py test` command doesn't give you more info about that error? Could you please post that info, if any?

Comment: Unfortunately uptating to Firefox 37 did not help either. The terminal tells me that my test has assertion error (title does not match because the page with "internal server error" message loads instead of expected page).

Comment: Have you tried to open and close the `WebDriver` inside the `setUp` and `tearDown` methods, instead of using the `setUpClass` and `tearDownClass` methods? Try it: they will be called before / after _each_ test method, so you will be sure to have a "clean new browser instance" for each test.

Comment: Just to support my previous comment: [http://stackoverflow.com/a/12012916/4594377](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12012916/4594377)

Comment: I tried. I originally began using classmethods instead of methods because I thought it might solve the problem. Everything worked when I used `unittest.TestCase` instead of `LiveServerTestCase`. But `TestCase` did not tell me current `live_server_url` and I needed it for my my selenium tests to work regardless of whether they are run on local or remote server so I could not just hardcode the url adress.

Comment: Maybe there is a solution not involving `LiveServerTestCase`?

Comment: `LiveServerTestCase` inherits from `TransactionTestCase`, so after each test _it truncates all the tables of the DB_ This could be a problem if you, like me, are using fixtures to populate the DB at the begin of each test (truncating all the tables means that also contenttypes, permissions, etc. are deleted). The code you posted here doesn't use fixtures, but I think it's just a sample of your actual code, so maybe that's the reason for the error (and I didn't find a solution for it, yet).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/74522/discussion-between-help-asap-and--).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally, the reason for the "internal server error" message is that WebDriver deletes all data from database on `quit()`, *including contenttypes and other default tables*.

This leads to an error when trying to load fixtures at the begin of the next test.

**N.B.** This behaviour is actually due to the way `TransactionTestCase` (from which `LiveServerTestCase` inherits) resets the database after the test runs: [it truncates all tables](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/testing/tools/#transactiontestcase).

---

So far, my solution is to load fixtures with all the data (also "default" Django data, e.g. contenttypes) on every test run.

```
class MyLiveServerTestCase(LiveServerTestCase):    
    """
    BaseClass for my Selenium test cases
    """
    fixtures = ['my_fixture_with_all_default_stuff_and_testing_data.json']

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.driver = WebDriver()
        cls.url = cls.live_server_url    
        super(MyLiveServerTestCase, cls).setUpClass()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.driver.quit()
        super(MyLiveServerTestCase, cls).tearDownClass()
```

Thanks to @help_asap for pointing out this flushing database on `quit()` problem!

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing up why my first `LiveServerTestCase` test worked fine, but my second one gave such bizarre errors. *Note to future googlers*, if you need a version of `LiveServerTestCase` that doesn't do this, you can use `class RealTransactionalLiveServerTestCase(LiveServerTestCase, TestCase): pass` to get the actual transaction functionality from `TestCase`.

Comment: @CoreDumpError child class is awesome!

Comment: Related Django ticket that might be of interest: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/23640