# Preserve data across LiveServerTestCase test methods?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing

Because `LiveServerTestCase` inherits from `TransactionTestCase`, the default behavior is to delete the test data at the end of every test method. I would like to use the `LiveServerTestCase` class, but preserve the test data from method to method. In this example, `test2` fails because the database is truncated at the end of `test1`.

My understanding is that if I were using `TestCase`, it would roll back the transactions at the end of each test and return the database to its starting condition. Is it possible for me to imitate that behavior while using the `LiveServerTestCase`?

```
class TestTheTests(LiveServerTestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpTestData(cls):
        print('running setUpTestData')
        call_command('loaddata', 'datasources.yaml' )

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        print('starting setUpClass')
        cls.setUpTestData() # load the data for the entire test class
        super().setUpClass()

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        print('finished tearDownClass')
        super().tearDownClass()

    def setUp(self):
        self.browser = webdriver.Chrome()

    def tearDown(self):
        self.browser.quit()
```

When I run both the tests together, this test passes:

```
    def test1(self):
        print('test 1 running')
        self.assertEquals(8, DataSource.objects.count(),'There should be 8 DataSource objects in test1')
```

This test fails:

```
    def test2(self):
        print('test 2 running')
        self.assertEquals(8, DataSource.objects.count(),'There should be 8 DataSource objects in test2')
```

Both would pass if the database records were not being dropped at the end of `test1`.

Comment: This comment suggests making a new class that inherits the transaction behavior from `TestCase`: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29378328/django-liveservertestcase-fails-to-load-a-page-when-i-run-multiple-tests#comment70408609_29533884

Answer (score 0):

Extract from: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/testing/overview/#rollback-emulation

> Django can reload that data for you on a per-testcase basis by setting the serialized_rollback option to True in the body of the TestCase or TransactionTestCase, but note that this will slow down that test suite by approximately 3x.

This will solve your problem:

```
class TestTheTests(LiveServerTestCase):
    serialized_rollback = True
    ...
```